# From Tycho, Kepler to Newton

Tags: book, videos

There are some [nice movies about math or mathematicians](https://medium.com/however-mathematics/13-must-see-mathematics-movies-inspired-by-true-events-1beda86255cd), however, the inspiring history from Tycho Brahe to Johannes Kepler to Isaac Newton seems are not covered.

This is indeed amazing, Tycho spent his whole life observing remote celestial objects, Kepler found the secrete links hidden among the numbers, then finally [Newton explained it with the law of universal gravitation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112668/derivation-of-keplers-laws), and calculs, the math he invented to explain the nature.

Unfortunately such exciting chapter of human intelligence is not made to a movie by any director, or a video by any youtube channel.

I wonder, if there's a book telling the story, with solid math explaining the theories?

Comment: I upvoted too quickly. I think this question is more appropriate to the History of Science and Mathematics SE: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: just in case someone comes here, I found Douglas W. MacDougal's [Newton's Gravity, An Introductory Guide to the Mechanics of the Universe](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-5444-1) close to what I'm looking for, though, due to the target, the author did not use calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Books.  Two classic books by Arthur Koestler:

*The Sleepwalkers: A History of Man's Changing Vision of the Universe*

*The Watershed: a Biography of Johannes Kepler*

[In fact, *The Watershed* is Part 4 of *The Sleepwalkers*, including much on Tycho.  Part 5 then goes on to Newton.]

Comment: thanks for the recommendation.. do you happen to know some books a bit more "hardcore", with more equations inside?